# Way to parse in PHP like in AWK for the last field such as $NF?

Tags: php, awk

In AWK I am able to take a variable field string delimited by commas and parse the last field by using the $NF variable in AWK.

Is there a way to do this in PHP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a one liner...

```
$NF = end(array_map('trim', explode(',', $commadelimitedstring)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myLastElement = end(array_values($yourArray));
```

The above works!